# SQL Select Query Logic with 2 Parts

Tags: sql-server

EDIT : I Want to Join the following Queries

QUERY1

```
SELECT     r.userId, r.programmeId, u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profileId, tblProgrammes.name, u.storeId, r.dateEnded AS lastPass, r.dateExpired
FROM         tblUserRepeatHistory AS r INNER JOIN
                      tblUsers AS u ON r.userId = u.id INNER JOIN
                      tblProgrammes ON r.programmeId = tblProgrammes.id
WHERE     (u.storeId = @storeId) AND (r.userId = @userId)
GROUP BY r.userId, r.programmeId, u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profileId, tblProgrammes.name, u.storeId, r.dateEnded, r.dateExpired
HAVING      (DATEDIFF(D, MAX(r.dateExpired), GETDATE() + 31) >= 0)
```

WITH

QUERY2

```
SELECT TOP (1) r.id, p.maxSteps
FROM tblUserQuestionnaireHistory AS r INNER JOIN
tblProgrammes AS p ON r.programmeId = p.id AND r.stepId = p.maxSteps
WHERE (r.userId = @UserId) AND (r.programmeId = @ProgrammeId) AND (r.success = 1)
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

The syntax Should be as follows

Select all from QUERY1 JOINED WITH QUERY2 WHERE QUERY2 doesn't record any records. I.e. if QUERY2 returns true than never mind returned the record from the first part

Select * from QUERY1 WHERE NOT EXISTS JOIN QUERY2 where @userId and @programmeId in query 2 come from QUery1

Comment: You don't specify which **version** of SQL Server..... if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you might want to look into using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) to set up your first select, and then join then results the CTE provides to the second SELECT you need.....

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outer apply` to find the `top 1` row matching your conditions:

```
select  *
from    tblUserRepeatHistory u
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    tblUserQuestionnaireHistory r
        on      r.userId = u.UserId
                and r.programmeId = u.programmeId
                and r.success = 1
                and r.stepId = 9
        ) as r
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT r.userId, r.programmeId, u.email, u.firstName, (SELECT TOP (1) r.id FROM tblUserQuestionnaireHistory AS r WHERE (r.userId = urh.UserId) AND (r.programmeId = urh.ProgrammeId) AND (r.success = 1) AND r.stepId = 9)
FROM tblUserRepeatHistory urh
where urh.UserId = @UserId and usr.ProgrammeId = @programmeId
```